# vb6 to vb.net for OracleInProcServer.OraDynaset

Tags: vb.net, datatable, vb6-migration

I am converting a project which is coded in old vb6 way. I am replacing the instances of OracleInProcServer.OraDynaset to Datatable for getting the data from database. But a form is generated in a dynamic way has the below code. i don't know how be there a alternate code for there in vb.net. Is there any way I can replace the below code without using dsAnswer As OracleInProcServer.OraDynaset.  I don't know what is ! here also and how it is working.

```html
Dim dsAnswer As OracleInProcServer.OraDynaset
        Select Case dsAnswer!Shape.Value
            Case 0 To 5
                iShapes = iShapes + 1



                'Load(f!shpCtrl(iShapes))
                frmDynaForm.shpCtrl.Load(iShapes)

                frmDynaForm.shpCtrl(iShapes).FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(DecodeColorDesc(Format$(dsAnswer!Color.Value)))
                'frmDynaForm.shpCtrl(iShapes).Shape = dsAnswer!Shape.Value
                frmDynaForm.shpCtrl(iShapes).Top = dsAnswer!Top.Value
                frmDynaForm.shpCtrl(iShapes).Left = dsAnswer!Left.Value
                frmDynaForm.shpCtrl(iShapes).Height = dsAnswer!Height.Value
                frmDynaForm.shpCtrl(iShapes).Width = dsAnswer!Width.Value
                frmDynaForm.shpCtrl(iShapes).BorderWidth = dsAnswer!BorderWidth.Value
                frmDynaForm.shpCtrl(iShapes).Visible = True


            Case -1
                iLines = iLines + 1


                'Load(f!lineCtrl(iLines))
                frmDynaForm.lineCtrl.Load(iShapes)
                frmDynaForm.lineCtrl(iLines).BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(DecodeColorDesc(Format$(dsAnswer!Color.Value)))
                frmDynaForm.lineCtrl(iLines).Y1 = dsAnswer!Top.Value
                frmDynaForm.lineCtrl(iLines).X1 = dsAnswer!Left.Value
                frmDynaForm.lineCtrl(iLines).Y2 = dsAnswer!Height.Value
                frmDynaForm.lineCtrl(iLines).X2 = dsAnswer!Width.Value
                frmDynaForm.lineCtrl(iLines).BorderWidth = dsAnswer!BorderWidth.Value
                frmDynaForm.lineCtrl(iLines).Visible = True

        End Select
```

Comment: VB6 uses the ! operator to refer to a TableDef in a DAO Database's TableDefs collection.

Comment: Is there any difference between dsAnswer.Item("Color").Value and dsAnswer!Color.Value

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820997.aspx), no. (That entry is identical to the one in MSDN October 2001.)

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I am looking for.